# Updating Basket quantity using ENTER clears the basket entirely

Tags: magento2, cart, shopping-cart

Trying to update the quantity in the cart with the ENTER key, the entire cart is deleted. Viewing the form code I realized that in addition to the "update cart" button there are also the "Continue Shopping" and "Clear Shopping Cart" buttons (hidden with display: none).
Then when you click ENTER the Update and CLEAR commands are activated both and the cart is empty.
I am not yet very expert on Magento, can you tell me which file to mood to solve the problem?

Comment: depends on the installation... are you using a custom theme? custom modules?

Comment: I have magento 2.3.1 with PORTO theme.